# "apt-get install linux-headers-generic" installed in directory different than $(uname-r)

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a newbie on Linux kernel. I was trying to install Linux header on ubuntu. I first tried

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

However, since the output of `$(uname -r)` is `4.4.0-18362-Microsoft`, the installation gives me the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.4.0-18362-Microsoft                                                         
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.4.0-18362-Microsoft'                                              
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.4.0-18362-Microsoft'
```

By searching on the internet, I found that linux headers do not exist on WSL. Therefore I tried something that is recommended on the internet, by doing

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Then I got a successful installation under `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic` and `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-51`. However, my team uses a makefile where the directory of the Linux headers is referred to using `$(uname -r)`, which is still `4.4.0-18362-Microsoft`. So whenever I do `make`, it still gives me the error

```
can't read /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-18362-Microsoft/...
```

Is there anyway I can install the headers or change `$(uname -r)` such that I can use `$(uname -r)` to refer to the directory?

Answer (score 1):

Create a symlink from **/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic** to /**usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-18362-Microsoft/**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and had a similar issue - but it wasn't Microsoft:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic-generic'
```

For me worked fine after I did as below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```